# How to add Dynamic captcha in Java

Tags: java, captcha

I want to add dynamic captcha on page.Whenever more than 3 request comes inspecific time from same IP address then Captcha will appear on the screen..

Comment: I assume there are lot of frameworks available. Did you try finding any on google?

Comment: Which framework, can you please tell some of them?

Comment: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Captchas_in_Java

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- You can write a code in servlet filter to check if many requests come from a specific IP within a specific time duration. In this case, you can add some flag in the session.
- Use this flag to check on the page if to display the captcha or not.

Answer (score 2):

- Create a servlet which dynamically creates the captcha. To create the captcha you can use [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org) in conjunction with [im4java](http://im4java.sourceforge.net/).
- In your HTML page embed an Image-Tag with the path to the servlet which generates the captcha.
- Count the number of requests to the captcha-generating servlet in your session. As long as the threshold has not been reached you may return an empty image to avoid any errors on the client side.
- If the threshold has been reached you generate the captcha. Store the value (i.e. the value the user has to enter in order to proceed) in the session.
- The user sees the captcha and has to enter its value.
- Compare the value the user has entered with the value stored in the session.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

A CAPTCHA (Completely Automated Public Turing test to tell Computers and Humans Apart) is a test to determine whether the user is human or not.

CAPTCHA provides a way to block bots from interacting with your site by providing something that's hard for them to read, but easy for people to read.

```
import java.util.Random;
public class GenerateCaptcha {
      /**
       * Generate Length between 5 and 8.
       * @return return length.
       */
      private static int generateRandomLength() {
            int length = 5 + Math.abs((random.nextInt()%4));
            return length;
      }

      /**
       *  Generate a CAPTCHA String consisting of random
       *  lower case & upper case letters, and numbers.
       */
      private static String generateCaptchaString(int length) {

            StringBuffer captchaBuffer = new StringBuffer();

            for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {

                  /** Generate the Random Character between 0 to 61.
                   * NOTE: Take abs value, because there may
                   * be ArrayIndexOutOfBount
                   * Exception for negative number*/
                  int rndCharIdx = Math.abs(random.nextInt()) % 62;

                  char character = characters[rndCharIdx];

                  captchaBuffer.append(character);
            }
            return captchaBuffer.toString();
      }

      private static Character[] characters = {'a','b','c','d','e','f',
            'g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u',
            'v','w','x','y','z','A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J',
            'K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y',
            'Z','0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9'};

      private static Random random = new Random();

      public static void main(String[] args) {

            int rndmCaptchaLen = generateRandomLength();

            String captcha = generateCaptchaString(rndmCaptchaLen);

            System.out.println("Random Captcha #"+captcha);
      }
}
```

More information on my blog:

http://javaexplorer03.blogspot.in/2016/12/program-to-generate-unique-captcha-to.html